# How to increase the font size in a pdf using c# with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: c#, font-size, wkhtmltopdf

A have created a pdf file from an .aspx page using the `wkhtmltopdf` converter. It's showing a smaller font size than the actual font shown on the page. So when I take the print out of the pdf file, it looks as if it has been compressed to a smaller size. Do any of you have any idea how can I set/increase the font size by number (14 or 15) or percentage using C# code? I'm using the string `switches` to fix the margin, page etc. as follows:

```
string switches = "";
switches += "--print-media-type ";
switches += "--margin-top 5mm --margin-bottom 5mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 30mm ";
switches += "--page-size A4 ";
```

Can you suggest how I can incorporate font size here? My page has different font types and sizes for different controls. I want to increase the font size for ALL elements (if possible, by some percentage).

Comment: Switch to EM as unit in your style sheet and increase the size of the  BODY style.

Comment: I'm convrting a .aspx page to PDF through C# code while I'm setting margin,page etc.There I want to set the font size.Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem above can be solved by the following code:--
I added this line of code and the newly created pdf file has exactly the font size what I want.

```
switches +="--disable-smart-shrinking";
```

It'll stop font shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't edit the html/css before sending it to wkhtmltopdf, try the `--minimum-font-size` option. If that doesn't work, and you don't mind making *everything* bigger, there is also `--zoom`.

Comment: Friends,I found out the answer.I've added a line of code to get elements in correct size,i.e:--

        switches += "--disable-smart-shrinking ";

It'll solve shrinking problem.